# how to get status of presence of a file using wildcard search

Tags: talend

In TALEND, I want to search a file on a specificities directory using wildcard search.
eg. /directory/Abc_2021*

And after this I need to put "if" triggers according to the presence of file. If the file is available then one subjob will get executed else another subjob will get executed.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `tFileList`, you specify the folder and the wildcard. Connect to a `tJava` with a OnSubjobOk connector. Connect the `tJava` to a `tRunJob` and specify the job to run if a file is present. Use a RunIf connector with the condition

```
((Integer)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_NB_FILE")) > 0
```

Add another `tRunJob`, specify the job to run if no file found, connect to the `tJava` with a RunIf connector with  the condition

```
((Integer)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_NB_FILE")) == 0
```

[image]